# printing info from weather utility

Tags: python, script

I've download the weather-util on raspberry pi.  Is there a way to print the info from a python script?
Say you want the weather info for jfk, so the command is weather jfk.

Comment: "the weather utility" - I'm sure there's more than one utility that does such a thing, so, you may want to be a little more specific

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the [`weather-util`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/weather-util) package from the repositories, Alex? If so, it would be helpful to [edit] your post to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks the "how do I insert a command line in a Python script" link worked.

Comment: I'm not sure if the system will let you flag your question as a duplicate if you want to mark it resolved; you could try that if you wanted. Glad to hear that link worked though.